# Getting varying read speed for files from the disk

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

I am developing a Java application to read multiple text files from the disk, modify them and write a modified file back to the disk. When I run the read test using "FileReadTestJavaGui-1.05.jar" from http://sourceforge.net/projects/filereadtest/files/filereadtest-java-gui/, I get read speed upwards of 250 MB/sec. When I run my test application given below, I get read speed of as low as 11.75 MB/sec. I am using ThreadPoolExecutor and not able to get a consistent read / write speed. Any suggestions for fixing this issue are very welcome. I ran these tests on a Windows 2008 Server R2 machine on a Dell dual quad core 2.4 GHz machine with 12 GB RAM.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class RunTest {
    private static String baseFileName = "C:/logs/input_";
    private static class FileReaderRunnable implements Runnable {
        public FileReaderRunnable(int threadID) {
            super();
            this.threadID = threadID;
        }
        int threadID = -1;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Thread.currentThread().setName("Thread-" + threadID);
            String writeBaseFileName = "c:/temp/output";
            String[] args = {baseFileName + threadID + ".log", writeBaseFileName + threadID + ".txt"};
            readAndWriteFileInputOutputStream(args);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int MAX_THREADS = 20;
        int coreThreadPoolSize = 2;
        int maxThreadPoolSize = 4;
        long threadKeepAliveTime = 12000000;
        int arrayBlockQueueSize = 400;
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                coreThreadPoolSize,
                maxThreadPoolSize,
                threadKeepAliveTime,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(arrayBlockQueueSize, true));
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {
            FileReaderRunnable frr = new FileReaderRunnable(i+1);
            executor.execute(frr);
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                print("********** executor.getPoolSize()=" + executor.getPoolSize());
                print("********** executor.getCorePoolSize()=" + executor.getCorePoolSize());
                print("********** executor.getActiveCount()=" + executor.getActiveCount());
                print("********** executor.getCompletedTaskCount()=" + executor.getCompletedTaskCount());
                print("********** executor.getTaskCount()=" + executor.getTaskCount());
                print("********** executor.isShutdown()=" + executor.isShutdown());
                print("********** executor.isTerminated()=" + executor.isTerminated());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    public static void readAndWriteFileInputOutputStream(String[] args) {
        try {
            String routineName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            String fInp = "c:\\temp\\input.txt";
            String fOut = "c:\\temp\\output.txt";
            if( args.length > 0 ) {
                fInp = args[0];
            }
            if( args.length > 1 ) {
                fOut = args[1];
            }
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            // delete the file if it exists
            File fff = new File( fOut );
            if( fff.exists() ) {
                fff.delete();
            }
            fff = null;
            fos = new FileOutputStream(fOut);
            fis = new FileInputStream( fInp );
            long readTime = 0;
            long writeTime = 0;
            final int FILE_CHUNK_SIZE = 16 * 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[ FILE_CHUNK_SIZE ];

            long sTOverall = System.nanoTime();
            final long fileLen = fis.available();
            for ( long restSize = fileLen; restSize > 0; ) {
                final int sizeToProcess = (int) java.lang.Math.min( restSize, FILE_CHUNK_SIZE );
                long sT = System.nanoTime();
                final int actuallyRead = fis.read( buffer, 0, sizeToProcess );
                readTime += System.nanoTime() - sT;
                restSize -= actuallyRead;
                long sT0 = System.nanoTime();
                fos.write(buffer);
                writeTime += System.nanoTime() - sT0;
            }
            sTOverall = System.nanoTime() - sTOverall;
            fff = new File(fOut);
            double size = ((double)fff.length()) / (1024 * 1024);
            double secTaken = ((double)writeTime) / 1000000000;
            print(routineName + ": Took: " + secTaken + " sec to write " + size + " MB which is " + (size/secTaken) + " MB/sec");
            fos.close();
            File fff2 = new File(fInp);
            size = ((double)fff2.length()) / (1024 * 1024);
            secTaken = ((double)readTime) / 1000000000;
            print(routineName + ": Took: " + secTaken + " sec to read " + size + " MB which is " + (size/secTaken) + " MB/sec");
            fis.close();
            print(routineName + ": Took " + sTOverall + " nanosec overall");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void print(String string) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

The results I get are as follows:

```
Thread-1: Took: 0.171561487 sec to write 100.015625 MB which is 582.9724768006936 MB/sec
Thread-2: Took: 0.174120658 sec to write 100.015625 MB which is 574.4041295777781 MB/sec
Thread-1: Took: 0.095193221 sec to read 100.00039100646973 MB which is 1050.4990791988196 MB/sec
Thread-1: Took 273077435 nanosec overall
Thread-2: Took: 0.095017056 sec to read 100.00039100646973 MB which is 1052.4467418404304 MB/sec
Thread-2: Took 273701058 nanosec overall
Thread-4: Took: 0.14674968 sec to write 100.015625 MB which is 681.538964854983 MB/sec
Thread-4: Took: 0.089255036 sec to read 100.00039100646973 MB which is 1120.3893414649424 MB/sec
Thread-4: Took 238318510 nanosec overall
Thread-3: Took: 0.151534826 sec to write 100.015625 MB which is 660.0174206818965 MB/sec
Thread-3: Took: 0.093351422 sec to read 100.00039100646973 MB which is 1071.2251496979845 MB/sec
Thread-3: Took 246756663 nanosec overall
Thread-5: Took: 0.149539881 sec to write 100.015625 MB which is 668.8224193517981 MB/sec
Thread-5: Took: 0.089968802 sec to read 100.00039100646973 MB which is 1111.5007511878364 MB/sec
Thread-5: Took 239927158 nanosec overall
Thread-6: Took: 0.153380444 sec to write 100.015625 MB which is 652.0754692821205 MB/sec
Thread-6: Took: 0.087988256 sec to read 100.00039100646973 MB which is 1136.519753346057 MB/sec
Thread-6: Took 241764966 nanosec overall
Thread-7: Took: 0.142689584 sec to write 100.015625 MB which is 700.9315059745355 MB/sec
Thread-7: Took: 0.088074798 sec to read 100.00039100646973 MB which is 1135.4030128626548 MB/sec
Thread-7: Took 231188741 nanosec overall
Thread-8: Took: 0.140693664 sec to write 100.015625 MB which is 710.8751180152648 MB/sec
Thread-8: Took: 0.085812695 sec to read 100.00039100646973 MB which is 1165.333299536505 MB/sec
Thread-8: Took 226884069 nanosec overall
Thread-9: Took: 0.105057511 sec to write 100.015625 MB which is 952.0083242786895 MB/sec
Thread-9: Took: 0.076369586 sec to read 100.00039100646973 MB which is 1309.4269099019305 MB/sec
Thread-9: Took 181834692 nanosec overall
Thread-10: Took: 0.113160569 sec to write 100.015625 MB which is 883.8381238609713 MB/sec
Thread-10: Took: 0.083640607 sec to read 100.00039100646973 MB which is 1195.5961893780818 MB/sec
Thread-10: Took 197200174 nanosec overall
********** executor.getPoolSize()=2
********** executor.getCorePoolSize()=2
********** executor.getActiveCount()=2
********** executor.getCompletedTaskCount()=10
********** executor.getTaskCount()=20
********** executor.isShutdown()=true
********** executor.isTerminated()=false
Thread-11: Took: 0.154032991 sec to write 100.015625 MB which is 649.3130098343672 MB/sec
Thread-11: Took: 8.420174029 sec to read 100.00039100646973 MB which is 11.876285533061127 MB/sec
Thread-11: Took 8574829737 nanosec overall
********** executor.getPoolSize()=2
********** executor.getCorePoolSize()=2
********** executor.getActiveCount()=2
********** executor.getCompletedTaskCount()=11
********** executor.getTaskCount()=20
********** executor.isShutdown()=true
********** executor.isTerminated()=false
Thread-12: Took: 0.140394781 sec to write 100.015625 MB which is 712.3884825889646 MB/sec
Thread-12: Took: 8.505642503 sec to read 100.00039100646973 MB which is 11.756947340685771 MB/sec
Thread-12: Took 8646511924 nanosec overall
Thread-13: Took: 0.143740254 sec to write 100.015625 MB which is 695.8080441405091 MB/sec
Thread-13: Took: 4.546878135 sec to read 100.00039100646973 MB which is 21.993197978346462 MB/sec
Thread-13: Took 4691105248 nanosec overall
********** executor.getPoolSize()=2
********** executor.getCorePoolSize()=2
********** executor.getActiveCount()=2
********** executor.getCompletedTaskCount()=13
********** executor.getTaskCount()=20
********** executor.isShutdown()=true
********** executor.isTerminated()=false
Thread-14: Took: 0.143977148 sec to write 100.015625 MB which is 694.6631905779936 MB/sec
Thread-14: Took: 5.020245761 sec to read 100.00039100646973 MB which is 19.91942143217911 MB/sec
Thread-14: Took 5164713374 nanosec overall
Thread-15: Took: 0.155099121 sec to write 100.015625 MB which is 644.8497216177002 MB/sec
Thread-15: Took: 3.628340768 sec to read 100.00039100646973 MB which is 27.560914864562612 MB/sec
Thread-15: Took 3783981095 nanosec overall
Thread-16: Took: 0.147386899 sec to write 100.015625 MB which is 678.5923693258518 MB/sec
Thread-16: Took: 3.865473212 sec to read 100.00039100646973 MB which is 25.870154964734425 MB/sec
Thread-16: Took 4013349692 nanosec overall
********** executor.getPoolSize()=2
********** executor.getCorePoolSize()=2
********** executor.getActiveCount()=2
********** executor.getCompletedTaskCount()=16
********** executor.getTaskCount()=20
********** executor.isShutdown()=true
********** executor.isTerminated()=false
Thread-17: Took: 0.145950813 sec to write 100.015625 MB which is 685.2693927782368 MB/sec
Thread-17: Took: 3.594029782 sec to read 100.00039100646973 MB which is 27.824029591324553 MB/sec
Thread-17: Took 3740485565 nanosec overall
Thread-18: Took: 0.143193164 sec to write 100.015625 MB which is 698.4664784696006 MB/sec
Thread-18: Took: 4.387502482 sec to read 100.00039100646973 MB which is 22.792099016861528 MB/sec
Thread-18: Took 4531185662 nanosec overall
********** executor.getPoolSize()=2
********** executor.getCorePoolSize()=2
********** executor.getActiveCount()=2
********** executor.getCompletedTaskCount()=18
********** executor.getTaskCount()=20
********** executor.isShutdown()=true
********** executor.isTerminated()=false
Thread-19: Took: 0.14751012 sec to write 100.015625 MB which is 678.0255144528389 MB/sec
Thread-19: Took: 5.882018447 sec to read 100.00039100646973 MB which is 17.001033218022773 MB/sec
Thread-19: Took 6030072471 nanosec overall
Thread-20: Took: 0.13555387 sec to write 100.015625 MB which is 737.8293589109629 MB/sec
Thread-20: Took: 4.122019495 sec to read 100.00039100646973 MB which is 24.260048048722226 MB/sec
Thread-20: Took 4258033501 nanosec overall
********** executor.getPoolSize()=0
********** executor.getCorePoolSize()=2
********** executor.getActiveCount()=0
********** executor.getCompletedTaskCount()=20
********** executor.getTaskCount()=20
********** executor.isShutdown()=true
********** executor.isTerminated()=true
```

Comment: Did you examine the source of FileReadTestJavaGui to see how their code differs from yours?  Also, it's not clear what you're asking here, as some of your threads seem to get speeds in the 1 GB/sec range.

Comment: I am using the FileInputBuffer as in the FileReadTestGui. My question is what do I do to get a high read speeds consistently for all the threads. Currently, only a few of these threads get a high read speed while the rest are getting very low read speeds.

Answer (score 1):

Your write time is consistent for all your runs.  Your read time starts off extremely fast (> 1 GB/s) but eventually bottoms out.  I suspect what is happening is you have exceeded the system's disk cache capacity.  For the first 10 threads, the data you were writing stuck around in the system's disk cache, and therefore reading was extremely fast.  After the 10th thread, you had written enough data that the system started discarding cached data, and actually had to go to disk to read the data.  It should have been keeping the MRU blocks around, but maybe not.  You don't specify what OS so it's not possible even to speculate on what's happening.

This is a cautionary tale that microbenchmarks are fraught with peril.  There's a lot of optimization going on behind your back on modern operating systems, such as JIT compilation, disk caching (in the OS, the disk controller, and the disk itself), etc, and you must consider these factors when benchmarking, especially basic operations such as Java code execution speed and I/O.

I suspect the FileReadTestJavaGui didn't write enough data to encounter the same problem.

The bottom line is you cannot get consistent results, *or even know exactly what it is you're measuring*, without an in-depth understanding of *everything* that happens between your code and the "bare metal".

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to mention that I ran these tests on a Windows 2008 Server R2 machine on a Dell dual quad core 2.4 GHz machine with 12 GB RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are not using direct I/O to avoid caching data in RAM (is it possible in Java?). If you are using Linux you might want to run vmstat to see what is happening or Perfmon if Windows. I am currently writing benchmarks and stress programs on Raspberry Pi. Following are vmstat results for a disk (SD card) test, firstly with direct I/O where the file cache stays small and CPU utilisation low. Second one is cached I/O where the cache can contain all for files used and reading data is from RAM at 100% CPU utilisation. RPi has only 512 MB relatively slow RAM. A further test with 4 x 164 MB files does not cache them for reading but repeated runs might have some caching when the OS realises that files are being be reread. Whatever file size, cached speeds can vary a lot.

```
vmstat 15 25 > vmstats44.txt
15 second periods, 25 samples
Write 4 files of 82 MB in 46 seconds =   7.1 MB/sec bo
Read 3 x 4 x 82 MB in 62 second       = 15.8 MB/sec bi
Reread 49200 x 64 KB in 167 seconds   = 18.4 MB/sec bi
Rereads 64 KB block for 1 second from 
164 blocks in one file

procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 1  0      0 349476   2772  33484    0    0    51   439 1264  229 15 30 53  2
 0  1      0 347428   2796  33532    0    0     2  6996 3793  914 17 42  0 41
 1  1      0 347172   2904  33592    0    0     6  6851 3736  849 11 41  0 48
 1  1      0 347172   2932  33616    0    0     1  7536 3996  931 11 46  0 43
 2  0      0 347048   2948  33616    0    0 13965  1053 6187 1264 14 18  0 68
 0  1      0 347048   2964  33616    0    0 16188     3 6524 1314 13 14  0 73
 1  0      0 347048   2972  33616    0    0 16427     3 6605 1333 12 14  0 74
 0  1      0 347048   2980  33616    0    0 16439     2 6607 1335 13 14  0 73
 2  0      0 347048   2996  33616    0    0 18253     3 7198 1471  7  9  0 84
 1  1      0 347048   3020  33616    0    0 18842     5 7393 1510  4 10  0 87
 0  1      0 346924   3044  33616    0    0 18833     6 7389 1512  2 10  0 88
 0  1      0 346924   3068  33616    0    0 18842     5 7393 1504  4 10  0 87
 1  0      0 346924   3092  33616    0    0 18859     6 7398 1509  3  8  0 89
 0  1      0 346924   3116  33616    0    0 18854     5 7390 1509  3  9  0 88
 0  1      0 346800   3140  33616    0    0 18859     5 7395 1508  4  9  0 87
 1  1      0 346800   3164  33616    0    0 18820     6 7385 1501  3 10  0 87
 1  1      0 346800   3188  33616    0    0 18842     5 7391 1506  3  8  0 89
 1  1      0 346800   3212  33616    0    0 18829     5 7386 1507  3  9  0 88
 0  1      0 346676   3236  33616    0    0 18816     6 7384 1495  4  9  0 88
 0  0      0 346800   3252  33552    0    0  7428     7 3632  640  4  4 59 32


Cached test  - see cache size details
Write 4 x 82 MB time 2.3, 9.1, 12.3, 2.4 seconds average 12.6 MB/sec bo
Read 19 x 4 x 82 MB in 63 seconds                       =  99 MB/sec cpu us sy
Reread 1158120 x 64 KB in 164 seconds                   = 441 MB/sec cpu us sy

procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 2  0      0 355484   3692  29308    0    0    60   345 1260  204 14 26 58  2
 0  3      0 124856   3976 254388    0    0    27 13562 1661 1889 16 34  0 50
 1  1      0  11476   4000 365356    0    0     0  8850 1413 2556 10 23  0 67
 1  0      0  11476   4012 365420    0    0     0     2 1750 1118 48 52  0  0
 1  0      0  11344   4020 365420    0    0     0     2 1270  122 50 50  0  0
 1  0      0  11352   4028 365420    0    0     0     4 1271   61 46 54  0  0
 1  1      0  11600   3616 365572    0    0    57     2 1292   77 44 56  0  0
 1  0      0  12320   1940 366340    0    0   254     6 1376  111 14 86  0  0
 1  0      0  11476   1964 367540    0    0    80     4 1304   91 14 86  0  0
 1  0      0  11352   1988 367540    0    0     0     5 1277   82 12 88  0  0
 1  0      0  11352   2012 367540    0    0     0     5 1275   79 13 87  0  0
 1  0      0  11228   2036 367540    0    0     0     5 1276   85 14 86  0  0
 2  0      0  11228   2060 367540    0    0     0     4 1276   80 13 87  0  0
 2  0      0  11228   2084 367540    0    0     0     5 1276   77 13 87  0  0
 1  0      0  11228   2108 367540    0    0     0     4 1276   83 13 87  0  0
 1  0      0  11104   2132 367540    0    0     0     4 1276   78 12 88  0  0
 1  0      0  10980   2300 367552    0    0     9     9 1282   80 11 89  0  0
 0  0      0 352104   2324  31696    0    0     1     5 1273   90 12 81  7  0
```